# Desktop distorted after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I just started using Ubuntu for the first time about an hour ago so please bear with me.  Prior to installing the Nvidia drivers the Ubuntu start-up screen is completely distorted(black screen with garbled graphical blocks).  However, from the Log-in screen onward its perfect.  Bright colors, crystal clear text, image fills the entire screen. Display is properly detected as an HP TV in Ubuntu Display settings.

Now, after installing the Nvidia drivers the Ubuntu boot screen shows up normally. Upon reaching the Log-in screen we run into trouble.  The image only fills about 85% of the screen(doesn't reach the edges), colors are duller, and text is blurry with lines through it.  Problem persists after logging in.  Display is detected as Laptop in Ubuntu Display settings.  Display is properly detected as an HP TV in the Nvidia-Settings but no setting changes seemed to fix the image.

I tried both the Recommended driver and the Post-Release driver, same problem.  As soon as I uninstalled it goes back to garbled boot screen but perfect picture afterward.

Any ideas? I can provide screen shots if that will help.

System specs:

```
Asus P5P43TD Pro
Intel C2D E7500
Nvidia 8800GT 512mb
4gb DDR3 1066
Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
HP md5880n
```

Comment: After further testing it would appear that the new drivers just don't like the HP TV.  The drivers work properly with my DELL 2412m even though they still detected the monitor as a Laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so apparently the new driver doesn't detect your monitor. Please take note of the version of the driver.. Then..

Revert the changes:
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
Then remove unneeded depends (make sure ubuntu-desktop doesn't show up in this list)
sudo apt-get autoremove

Then remove the ppa:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

`ls` #to see what's in the directory

Remove any entries that have the form: ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates*

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-*
```

Then update and reinstall the original version

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then run the nvidia-settings util and take note of the version. It should be different than above.

Then reboot for the reverted driver to take effect.

Also, this TV is supposed to be 1920x1080p correct? If so, when you run the nvidia-settings utility and click to change the resolution (may be on auto), is there 1920x1080p there? Then click apply? Also, there may be a setting for scaling or stretch.

Did you try clicking the Ubuntu icon and selecting "Ubuntu 2d" on login? Does it make any difference?

Comment: Yeah its a few years old. Here's the output if you still need it: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92 (GeForce 8800 GT) (rev a2)  I'll read up on that other link too.  Thank You for taking time to help.

Comment: I have it hooked up to an HP md5880n 58" DLP via DVI-to-HDMI cable. I was using the current approved nvidia driver.  I think its 295.40. I got it through the additional drivers app.

Comment: Ok I did everything listed and after it finished I rebooted. Screen  is crystal clear but: In Ubuntu Display settings it still list the Display as Laptop and I'm limited to 800x600 and 1024x768. When I go into nvidia-settings it says "You do not appear to be running the Nvidia X Driver. Please run your X configuration file(just run 'nvidia-xconfig' as root) and restart the X server.

Comment: When I try to remove the ppa it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: Oh wow, its 3:30am.  I'm going to hit the sack and check back tomorrow with a clearer head. Maybe I should just re-install the whole thing.  I wouldn't lose more than a few bookmarks in Firefox.  Thanks for all your help, even though the problem hasn't been roped in I've learned a lot.