# Purple Screen, first time using Ubuntu

Tags: installation, nvidia, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

It's my first time using Ubuntu and after my first reboot I loaded Ubuntu and a purple screen appeared. I've read it may have something to do with the graphics drivers. I have a Nvidia GTX 560 and I do not know how to install the drivers from this purple screen, I can access recovery mode and I downloaded Ubuntu using the windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

[How Install NVidia Driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

and this one:

[Distorted after installing NVidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129056/desktop-distorted-after-installing-nvidia-drivers)

and this one:

[Step by Step install NVidia](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.user/441583)

Answer (score 0):

In recovery mode boot in to the terminal with network support. Then typ this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```